# How can i check Parse PFRelation object is empty or contains data?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have parse query

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"Organization")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
   (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
   if error == nil {
      // this Organization contains some users as relation
      let users = object["users"] // this is PFRelation class

   }
}
```

All i wanted to check above `users` field (PFRelation) contains or pointing any users or not, if it is contains/pointing anything then i can do the relational query of `_User` class. So how can i check `users` contains/pointing something or not?

Comment: i think put your object in the IF condition it will check if user is nill or not!

Comment: no i have checked it. its always true.

Comment: can you show me show data over parse i mean that PFRelation class?

Comment: Have you tried "if users == nil"?